# How to pass object to callback which is defined inside an object/class?

Tags: javascript, callback

Following is a simple class definition. this.bounds is undefined in the console so i am wondering how can i access and alter bounds inside a callback. The goal is after the image is loaded, the bounds will be set to bounds.width = image.width etc. Thanks!

```
        function Car()  {
            this.image = new Image();            
            this.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);                
            this.setImage = function(ii){

                this.image.src = ii;

                this.image.onload = function () {

                   console.log("image was loaded " + this.bounds);

                }


            };

        }
```

Comment: Can you try doing : this.image.onload = function () {

                   console.log("image was loaded " + this.bounds);

                }.bind(this)

Comment: ok that worked. can you add a little more explanation what bind is for. i will accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: You can assingn `this.image` to a `var`, then used `varName.bounds`, so the `this` is no longer bound to the current Object. You can also create another Constructor then just return a new instance of that inside a method defined in your other Constructor.

Comment: @user734861 Have added the answer. Please refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing :

```
this.image.onload = function () { console.log("image was loaded " + this.bounds); }.bind(this)
```

"bind" is used to bind the current scope of this to any function.
Whenever you call the function in future, the bound reference of this will be used.

Please refer this link : [what is bind in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onload` callback `this` no longer points to `Car` instance but to image because it's called by `image` object when image is loaded. To access `Car` methods inside this callback you can:

- use `bind` method which returns new function inside which `this` is set the to value passed as argument to `bind`

  ```
  this.image.onload = function () {

     console.log("image was loaded " + this.bounds);

  }.bind(this)
  ```

  You can read more about `bind` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)
- in ES2015 you can use arrow function which also preserves `this` value:

  ```
  function Car()  {
      this.image = new Image();            
      this.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); 
      this.setImage = function(ii){

          this.image.src = ii;

          this.image.onload = () => {

             console.log("image was loaded " + this.bounds);

          }

      };

  }
  ```

  You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- you can also define a variable that will hold a value of `this`

  ```
  function Car()  {
      this.image = new Image();            
      this.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); 
      var self = this;
      this.setImage = function(ii){

          this.image.src = ii;

          this.image.onload = function () {

             console.log("image was loaded " + self.bounds);

          }

      };

  }
  ```

Comment: The Arrow function part you wrote is incorrect. It's just that when using a function that is not a property of `this` within a Constructor, `this` normally refers to the global Object, but with an Arrow functio n `this` refers to the Object instance.

Comment: `this.image.onload` will bind `this` to Constructor instance and never even create a image `onload` Event at all, so this technique is pointless.

Comment: Example with arrow function works as expected. Please remeber to create instance of Car class using `new` keyword, e.g. `var car = new Car();`

Answer (score -1):

"this" inside function image.onload() is actually scoped under function setImage(), which definitely don't have this.bounds defined, hence you got it undefined.

One solution could be to assign this to any variable just before the line: `this.image.onload = function () {`

so it will change to:

```
var that = this;
this.image.onload = function () {
    console.log("image was loaded " + that.bounds);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should see this:

```
var doc, bod, htm, Img, C, E; // for reuse on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;

C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Img = function(src, complete, context){
  this.image = C('img');
  var img = this.image;
  var cx = context || this;
  img.addEventListener('load', function(eventObj){
    complete.call(cx, eventObj);
  });
  img.src = src;
  this.imgMethod = fuction(){
    this.newProp = 'this in here refers to instance of Img';
  }
}
Car = function(){
  this.setImg = function(src, complete){
    return new Img(src, complete);
  }
}
var what = new Car; // no args it's okay to not use () with new
var someImg = what.setImg('yourImgSrc.png', function(){
  this.imgMethod(); console.log(this.newProp);
});
someImg.image.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  var bc = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var xy = {x:ev.clientX-bc.left, y:ev.clientY-bc.top};
  console.log(xy);
});

});
```

Note: this is only an example of `this` binding using `call`